# Error 1 Use of unassigned local variable 'rental'

Tags: c#

I get the error. The way I am looking at is I want the value that is returned from dayrental() * 19.95 to be stored in rental.

Use of unassigned local variable 'rental'

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        double rental;
        if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
            rental = dayrental() * 19.95;
        label4.Text = Convert.ToString(rental);




    }

    private void label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    public double dayrental()
    {
        var timeSpan = dateTimePicker2.Value - dateTimePicker1.Value;
        var rentalDays = timeSpan.Days;
        return (double) rentalDays;          
        //label4.Text = Convert.ToString(rentalDays);   
    }
```

Comment: I have to appologize for that real stupid question.

Comment: Not stupid.. It happens, and until you recognize the error, it takes time to understand it (I bet you'll recognize it from now on.. (-: ).

Comment: No such thing as a stupid question, this is what this site was built for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this message appears is that the compiler does not allow you to use an unassigned variable.

Let's here consider that your `CheckBox.Checked` property is false, what happens? You're trying to convert the value of your variable. At the end, you're using it! But how should the compiler know what value it's worth?

Here's a link that explains this error in depth: [`Compiler Error CS0165`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/4y7h161d%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

You need to tel the compiler that you know what you're doing. How? By initializing a default value to your variable. It may be some of the following:

```
double rental = default(double);
```

or

```
double rental = 0;
```

Or else, you may want that your form displays no value at all when this `CheckBox` is not `Checked`. Then, you would need a nullable type of double.

```
double? rental = null;
```

or

```
double? rental = default(double?);
```

While using this nullable double value type, this will allow you to display nothing when the `CheckBox.Checked = false`. Now, you should ask yourself whether you want zero (`0`) to be displayed when the `CheckBox` is not `Checked`.

By the way, the `if` condition only requires a boolean expression in its parentheses, and that's exactly what the `CheckBox.Checked` property is, so no need to compare it against `true`.

```
double? rental = null;

if (CheckBox1.Checked) 
    rental = DayRental() * 19.95;

label4.Text = Convert.ToString(rental);
```

Following this simple rule, you should be able to never ever again get this error.

Does this help?

Comment: I'm new to C# (coming from Java) and didn't know about default(). Thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

if checkBox1 is not checked, `rental` will not get a value. That's not good (-:

The idiomatic solution is assigning a default value,
But on your case, I think this is better:

```
if (checkBox1.Checked) //same as "==true" only prettier
{
 rental = dayrental() * 19.95;
 label4.Text = Convert.ToString(rental);
}
```

But I can't really know the context, so I can't tell.
Anyhow you get the point - `rental` must **definitely** get a value. In your code it might not get a value..

Answer (score 0):

initialize it with 0.0 then it will be assinged a value...

```
double rental = 0.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double rental = 0.0;
if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
        rental = dayrental() * 19.95;
label4.Text = Convert.ToString(rental);
```

That way if the checkbox is not checked then rental will have a value.

Comment: Why do you assume he wants zero to be desplayed in label4, when checkBox1 is not checked?

Comment: I'm assuming he is intelligent enough to replace the 0 with the value he wants.